# Writing a NSArray to file

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to save/write an Array to the documents directory, and I am completely stuck. I have checked this code with multiple sources online. I switched from and NSArray to a NSMutableArray and that didn't work. From what I can tell is the file isn't being written, because test is coming back null. Thanks in advance

```
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithData:data1];

NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:results];
// Create a dictionary from the JSON string  

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EmployeeData.plist"];

//NSLog(@"the path is %@, the array is %@", path, array2);

/////write to file/////
[array2 writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSLog(@"the test is %@", test);
```

** update **

I added these lines of code

```
BOOL write = [results writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"did it right? %@", write);
```

and write is null, what does that mean?

This is one of the many objects in my Array

```
{
     0 = "<null>";
    1 = "John Doe";
    10 = 512;
    11 = "<null>";
    12 = 1;
    13 = 1;
    2 = Doe;
    3 = Jon;
    4 = "<null>";
    5 = johndoe;
    6 = "<null>";
    7 = "<null>";
    8 = "john@doe.com";
    9 = "<null>";
    Type = 1;
    Active = 1;
    Depart = "<null>";
    Emp = "<null>";
    Ext = "<null>";
    FirstName = Jim;
    Fl = 512;
    Name = "John Doe";
    Log = jd;
    Mobile = "<null>";
    Title = "<null>";
}
```

Do the null values have anything to do with it?

SOLVED!!

I realized that the null values may have been causing some issues, so i changed my query to take care of that and it saved instantly. The above code is 100% correct and it works!

thanks for the help

Comment: You could cheat and write `[array2 description]` to the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), `writeToFile:` only works if your array's contents are limited to a handful of types (`NSString`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` objects).  If you have any other type of object in your array, then it will not write to file correctly (or at all).

Note also that `writeToFile:` returns a boolean value indicating whether or not the operation succeeded.

If your array contains incompatible types, you will have to look at using something like [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to serialize your data instead.

Comment: what i have is an array from a parsed website. i got the info in the array from JSON. So it is an array of objects. do you think that has anything to do with it not working?

Comment: Yes, probably some of your objects are of incompatible types.  You can check very simply by doing something like:  `for (NSObject* obj in array) { NSLog("%@", [obj class]); }`.  Note that if you have a complex JSON data structure then you may want to modify the loop to recurse through nested arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: i just added what one of my objects looks like in the description above

Comment: You've got a bunch of null items in there, which I assume are actually `NSNull` instances, which are not one of the supported types.

Comment: Hi Aroth, please can you explain the difference in above type and class which we create from NSObject? their must be some reason why we can write NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects but not my customClass subclass of NSObject.