# Save some info in any external file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am developing a guest list(NSMutableArray) and I would like to know If can I create and save this Array in any kind of external file such as .txt .pdf (or another extension)?

Any ideas for do this??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Xcode is a development tool, it is not your run time environment. This question has nothing to do with Xcode... but it does have to do with Objective C.

Comment: sounds like a great opportunity to edit the question to change the tags to be more relevant, @Mah !

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I agree but I don't like editing people's posts before they've had a chance to understand the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing array contents to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328978/writing-array-contents-to-a-file) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003244/writing-a-nsarray-to-file

Comment: Please note that as you enter your question into SO, you will be shown possibly related questions. Always check those before actually posting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSArray (which is what NSMutableArray derives from) has a ["`writeToURL:atomically:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToURL:atomically:) method, which takes a file URL.

Now, [if your array contains ***ONLY*** objects of the Objective-C types NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray or NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010363/nsarray-writetofile-fails), you should be okay.  If you have some custom objects, you'll need to write archiving / unarchiving coder methods which will allow those custom object's data to be written out to a file and read from a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new developing with Objective C and I didn't know if I could do it, do you have any example where I can see the code?

Comment: [This related (or potentially even duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19595293/981049)) question has the answer (and code example) you need.